# Package-qualified names. Differences (if any) between Package::<&var> vs &Package::var?

Tags: package, raku

Reading through https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Package-qualified_names it outlines qualifying package variables with this syntax:

```
Foo::Bar::<$quux>; #..as an alternative to Foo::Bar::quux;
```

For reference the package structure used as the example in the document is:

```
class Foo {
    sub zape () { say "zipi" }
    class Bar {
        method baz () { return 'Þor is mighty' }
        our &zape = { "zipi" };   #this is the variable I want to resolve
        our $quux = 42;
    }
}
```

The same page states this style of qualification doesn't work to access `&zape` in the Foo::Bar package listed above:

> (This does not work with the &zape variable)

Yet, if I try:

```
Foo::Bar::<&zape>;  # instead of   &Foo::Bar::zape;
```

it is resolves just fine.

Have I misinterpreted the document or completely missed the point being made? What would be the logic  behind it 'not working' with code reference variables vs a scalar for example?

Comment: Yes agree. The statement *"... does not work ..."* is confusing, as it "works" for me too, `say Foo::Bar::<&zape>` gives the same (pointy block variable) as `say &Foo::Bar::zape`

Comment: The documents are incorrect.

Comment: Well, there are two zapes. That makes it confusing. I'll try to fix that. It should simply have said it does not work with the Foo::zape variable, since it's got lexical scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JJ and Moritz have provided useful answers.

This nanswer is a whole nother ball of wax. I've written and discarded several nanswers to your question over the last few days. None have been very useful. I'm not sure this is either but I've decided I've finally got a first version of something worth publishing, regardless of its current usefulness.

In this first installment my nanswer is just a series of observations and questions. I also hope to add an *explanation* of my observations based on what I glean from spelunking the compiler's code to *understand* what we see. (For now I've just written up the start of that process as the second half of this nanswer.)

> Differences (if any) between `Package::<&var>` vs `&Package::var`?

They're fundamentally different syntax. They're not fully interchangeable in where you can write them. They result in different evaluations. Their result can be different things.

Let's step thru lots of variations drawing out the differences.

```
say Package::<&var>; # compile-time error: Undeclared name: Package
```

So, forget the `::<...>` bit for a moment. P6 is looking at that `Package` bit and demanding that it be an already declared name. That seems simple enough.

```
say &Package::var; # (Any)
```

Quite a difference! For some reason, for this second syntax, P6 has no problem with those two arbitrary names (`Package` and `var`) not having been declared. Who knows what it's doing with the `&`. And why is it `(Any)` and not `(Callable)` or `Nil`?

Let's try declaring these things. First:

```
my Package::<&var> = { 42 } # compile-time error: Type 'Package' is not declared
```

OK. But if we declare `Package` things don't really improve:

```
package Package {}
my Package::<&var> = { 42 } # compile-time error: Malformed my
```

OK, start with a clean slate again, without the `package` declaration. What about the other syntax?:

```
my &Package::var = { 42 }
```

Yay. P6 accepts this code. Now, for the next few lines we'll assume the declaration above. What about:

```
say &Package::var(); # 42
```

\o/ So can we use the other syntax?:

```
say Package::<&var>(); # compile-time error: Undeclared name: Package
```

Nope. It seems like the `my` didn't declare a `Package` with a `&var` in it. Maybe it declared a `&Package::var`, where the `::` just happens to be part of the name but isn't about packages? P6 supports a bunch of ["pseudo" packages](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#Pseudo-packages). One of them is `LEXICAL`:

```
say LEXICAL::; # PseudoStash.new(... &Package::var => (Callable) ...
```

Bingo. Or is it?

```
say LEXICAL::<&Package::var>(); # Cannot invoke this object
                                # (REPR: Uninstantiable; Callable)
```

What happened to our `{ 42 }`?

Hmm. Let's start from a clean slate and create `&Package::var` in a completely different way:

```
package Package { our sub var { 99 } }
say &Package::var();   # 99
say Package::<&var>(); # 99
```

Wow. Now, assuming those lines above and trying to add more:

```
my Package::<&var> = { 42 } # Compile-time error: Malformed my
```

That was to be expected given our previous attempt above. What about:

```
my &Package::var = { 42 }   # Cannot modify an immutable Sub (&var)
```

Is it all making sense now? ;)

## Spelunking the compiler code, checking the grammar

<sup>1</sup> I spent a long time trying to work out what the deal *really* is before looking at the source code of [the Rakudo compiler](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo). This is a footnote covering my initial compiler spelunking. I hope to continue it tomorrow and turn this nanswer into an answer this weekend.

The good news is it's just P6 code -- most of Rakudo is written in P6.

The bad news is knowing where to look. You might see the `doc` directory and then [the compiler overview](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/docs/compiler_overview.pod). But then you'll notice the overview doc has barely been touched since 2010! Don't bother. Perhaps [Andrew Shitov's "internals" posts](https://perl6.online/category/perl-6-internals/) will help orient you? Moving on...

In this case what I am interested in is understanding the precise nature of the `Package::<&var>` and `&Package::var` forms of syntax. When I type "syntax" into GH's repo search field the second file listed is [the Perl 6 Grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp). Bingo.

Now comes the ugly news. The Perl 6 Grammar file is 6K LOC and looks super intimidating. But I find it all makes sense when I keep my cool.

Next, I'm wondering what to search for on the page. `::` nets 600+ matches. Hmm. `::<` is just 1, but it is in an error message. But in what? In [`token morename`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f18af941391473a8105fc825ddcb77c0ef8a4d6b/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L579-L591). Looking at that I can see it's likely *not* relevant. But the `'::'` near the start of the token is just the ticket. Searching the page for `'::'` yields 10 matches. The first 4 (from the start of the file) are more error messages. The next two are in the above `morename` token. 4 matches left.

The next one appears a quarter way thru [`token term:sym<name>`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f18af941391473a8105fc825ddcb77c0ef8a4d6b/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L3081-L3168). A "name". .oO ( `Undeclared name: Package` So maybe this is relevant? )

Next, [`token typename`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f18af941391473a8105fc825ddcb77c0ef8a4d6b/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L3301-L3329). A "typename". .oO ( `Type 'Package' is not declared` So maybe this is relevant too? )

[`token methodop`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f18af941391473a8105fc825ddcb77c0ef8a4d6b/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L3874-L3896). Definitely not relevant.

Finally [`token infix:sym<?? !!>`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f18af941391473a8105fc825ddcb77c0ef8a4d6b/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4131-L4145). Nope.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of differences, but `Foo::Bar::<&zape>` can also be modified to use `{}` instead of `<>`, which then can be used with something other than literals, like this:

```
my $name = '&zape';
Foo::Bar::{$name}()
```

or

```
my $name = 'zape';
&Foo::Bar::{$name}()
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `::(...)` to get a **lot** [more power](https://docs.perl6.org/language/packages#index-entry-%3A%3A%28%29).

Answer (score 4):

There are no differences between Package::<&var> and &Package::var.

```
package Foo { our $var = "Bar" };
say $Foo::var === Foo::<$var>; # OUTPUT: «True␤»
```

Ditto for subs (of course):

```
package Foo { our &zape = { "Bar" } };
say &Foo::zape === Foo::<&zape>;# OUTPUT: «True␤»
```

What the documentation (somewhat confusingly) is trying to say is that package-scope variables can only be accessed if declared using our. There are two `zape`s, one of them has got lexical scope (subs get lexical scope by default), so you can't access that one. I have raised [this issue](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2848) in the doc repo and will try to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: I counter claim: **1** There are differences between `Package::<&var>` and `&Package::var` and **2** Package-scope variables can be accessed even if not declared using our. Maybe I'm wrong but I'll write a (n)answer to elaborate.

Comment: @raiph if they are not declared using ours they are not package-scoped, but lexical-scoped. `class` is not declared "our", but is package scoped by default; methods ditto. However, subs are lexically declared by default. Maybe there should be a table somewhere with default scope of different things...

Comment: I've concluded my counter claim **2** is a dud. I've upvoted your comment above. And I've finally published a first installment about my counter claim **1**.